# Google Sheets formula to lookup value for all rows in another sheet by column names and returning value by column name

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a `Sheet1` with data like this:

| one | two | three | four |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c | d |
| e | f | g | h |
| i | j | k | l |
| m | n | o | p |

I have `Sheet2` with data like this:

| alpha | value 1 |
| --- | --- |
| c |  |
| k |  |
| g |  |
| c |  |

For each row in `Sheet2`, I want to look up `Sheet2`.`A2:A` in `Sheet1` according to a `lookup column name` in `Sheet1` and returning values from the associated row in `Sheet1` by `return column name` in `Sheet1`.

So, a few examples:

- Lookup `Sheet2`.`A2:A` in `Sheet1`.`three` and return `Sheet1`.`one`
- Lookup `Sheet2`.`A2:A` in `Sheet1`.`two` and return `Sheet1`.`four`

The idea is the formula would specify the `lookup column name` and `return column name` and I'd just change it for each lookup I need to do.

Imagine the formula was something like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  SOMEFORMULA(
      A2:A,                          # lookup this value
      GETCOLUMN(Sheet1, "three"),    # in this column in Sheet1
      GETCOLUMN(Sheet1, "one")       # and return the value from this column in Sheet1
  )
)
```

So, the expected result is:

| alpha | value |
| --- | --- |
| c | a |
| k | i |
| g | e |
| c | a |

I can use the new Google Sheet formulas they just released -- except named ranges. I feel like there is some clever trick using them, but I can't come up with it.

Comment: Can you share your approach for solving this problem?

Comment: What do you mean? I have not solved it.

Comment: i mean What did you try?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: I think the issue was I didn't even know where to start. I stared at this for a few hours trying to think of what might work but just kept coming up blank. :/

Comment: The best way is to just do something. Put in any function, any lookup and test and see what comes up. Don't try to be perfect or to achieve your goal, but just trying to come up with anything is better than nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try on below formula:

```
=BYROW(A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)),LAMBDA(x,INDEX(Sheet1!A:D,MATCH(x,INDEX(Sheet1!A:D,,MATCH("three",Sheet1!A1:D1,0)),0),MATCH("one",Sheet1!A1:D1,0))))
```

By `XLOOKUP()` function.

```
=BYROW(A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)),LAMBDA(x,XLOOKUP(x,FILTER(Sheet1!A2:D,Sheet1!A1:D1="three"),FILTER(Sheet1!A2:D,Sheet1!A1:D1="one"),"")))
```

[Sample Sheet Link.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uuhzlutlFWnFVnJKs5wywQTjEedE0Rdd2U6uGZz3yVI/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks for the credit. But a brief explanation(1 or 2 sentences) would be better. Canned reply coming up

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @TheMaster Thanks for reminding. Good suggestion. I will try to make explanation of part of formulas.

Comment: Both of these seem to work. Thank you. Any reason to pick one over the other? I also find it interesting to use `A2:INDEX` over `ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A <> ""...` since the `ARRAYFORMULA` will account for blank rows in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Use `HLOOKUP` to the get the correct column in Sheet1 and `XLOOKUP` to get the corresponding  column A value:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  XLOOKUP(
    A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)),
    HLOOKUP("three",Sheet1!A1:Z,SEQUENCE(ROWS(Sheet1!A1:Z)),0),
    Sheet1!A1:A
  )
)
```